# Modern looking interface for diff/meld type program (Mac OSX)

Tags: diff, meld

I'm using Mac OSX, and I was wondering if there was a good program for comparing two text files for differences? I have meld and the interface looks pretty old. It's just a small cosmetic thing, but is there a better diff comparison program out there for Macs?

Comment: You could check these ones (from a similar question asked at stackexchange): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229142/what-are-the-alternatives-for-meld-graphical-diff-tool-on-osx

Comment: AlternativeTo.net is now a good place to look for these queries: https://alternativeto.net/software/meld/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have or download XCode, you can use an app that comes with it called FileMerge.